# Composition with inheritance?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, uml, composition

my question is if it's possible/right to model something like this:

[image]

The problem is that tutorial can't exist without the lecture, BUT they're both very very similar in their attributes and methods, that's why I thought that maybe it could be easier to have an inheritance there. Thanks for the ideas and answers

Comment: It's possible. Did you try it and it didn't work?

Comment: not yet, i'm working on the design of my application and i wasn't sure if it could work like that, i'm pretty new in UML things, that's why i'm asking because it looks a little bit weird, but i didn't find any better solution

Comment: You should try before asking. It's a good habit to have, and you can usually get things figured out faster.

Comment: And you can try it on a small scale with just three classes, the ones you have here. It'd probably take about as much time and effort as it would to create the UML diagram and poet this question.

Comment: I know it's not so hard to try it at first, but I also didn't know if it's correct to do it in this way so I wanted to avoid some basic mistake, that's all. Thanks anyway for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work just fine.  There is nothing wrong with your model .... though it is conventional to draw the diagram with the superclass *above* the subclasses, not below them as your diagram does.